# Content of the ServletResponseObject or servletresponsewrapper

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, aspectj

I have a simple web application running in Tomcat. There is a servlet which is forwarding the request and response to a jsp page which in turn prints something to the browser.

Now I have an aspect which captures the response. In this case a HttpServletResponse. Now what I want to do is that I want to capture the reponse and add some content in it to be displayed in the browser through JSP page.

I dont want to add the content in the jsp page rather I want to add some content without changing my jsp or servlet, using runtime weaving functionality of aspectJ.

I have not been able to figure out any solution yet.Please help me with this.Thanks.

Comment: No.I dont..Voting up requires some credit which i dont have.

Comment: Voting up and accepting are two different actions. If you open a question asked by yourself you can see a check on the left side under the points, if you click on it the question will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't do that with the `response`. `Request` object is a better candidate for that. You must understand that `JSP` is a server-side technology, therefore your `request` used to be alive in the `JSP` page.

Moreover, I would suggest you to look at [Servlet Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html), those are meant for this kinda scenarios.

Comment: But sir,I have a simple doubt..Cant we see the contents of a HttpServletResponse object coming out of the compiled JSP pages.I have tried to apply aspect around the jsp pages.But no luck.There is no such API also.